# percentage and consumption arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic

> Due to an increment of 50% in the price of egg a person is able to buy
>   4 eggs less for Rs. 24. Find the initial cost of per dozen egg?

I am getting the answer as 24. However, the answer given in the book is 36. Please help regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let :

$p$ = unit price of egg,

$n$ = number of eggs.

1) $p \times n =24$ --- before increase of price

2) $1.5 p \times (n-4) = 24$ --- after increase of price.

*It seems that the answer provided in the book is wrong*...

$36$ must be the cost per dozen **after** the price increase.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**

Let $n_b,n_a$ denote the amounts (before and after) of the eggs you could get for Rs. $24$, and $p_b,p_a$ denote the likewise prices. Then
$$
p_b n_b = 24 = p_a n_a
$$
and you also have the constraints
$$
p_a = 1.5 p_b \quad \text{and} \quad n_a = n_b-4 \ge 1.
$$

Can you solve this now?